# How do I converge with acync functions?

Tags: functional-programming, async-await, ramda.js

I have a function which I want to make a point free with **converge**:

```
const getProfileAndRepos = R.converge(R.merge, [
    x => getProfile(x),
    x => getRepos(x)
])
```

My `getProfile` and `getRepos` are `async` functions.
When `getProfileAndRepos('john')` is invoked I get back:

`f.apply(...).then is not a function`

### UPDATE:

I kinda find a solution;

```
const getProfileAndRepos = R.converge(R.identity, [
    x => Promise.all([getProfile(x), getRepos(x)])
])
```

but now I get `[object, object]` but I want to unnest it so I get `[profile: {}, repos: []]`

This now might be a bit off the topic... sorry

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace of the error?

Answer (score 1):

I got it done making outer function:

```
const getData = async player => {
    const [profile, repos] = await Promise.all([
        getProfile(player),
        getRepos(player)
    ])
    return {
        profile,
        repos
    }
}

const getProfileAndRepos = R.converge(R.identity, [x => getData(x)])
```